# Animate element to another element's position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate an image so it will cover another one.
This is what I have tried, but with no success:

```
var xrect = $("#black").offset().left;
var yrect = $("#black").offset().top;

var xlogo = $("#logo").offset().left;
var ylogo = $("#logo").offset().top;
$('.logo').transition({ x: xrect + 'px', y: yrect + 'px' });
```

The HTML is:

```
<img class="logo" id="logo" onclick="animateLogo()" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
<br />
<img class="black" id="black" src="images/black.png" alt="black logo"/>
```

Does anyone know of an example doing something of this nature?

Comment: Are you using some `transition` plugin?

Comment: Seems to work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6hvaG/1/)... Have you included [jquery.transit.min.js](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.min.js)...?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YC68q/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `transition` function is not a default JQuery implementation. Try `animate` instead : http://api.jquery.com/animate/

I have added a z-index value to be sure that your logo will be above your rectangle.

Set your image style position to absolute like @dfsq advices

```
    img {position: absolute; z-index: 1;}

    var xrect = $("#black").offset().left;
    var yrect = $("#black").offset().top;

    var xlogo = $("#logo").offset().left;
    var ylogo = $("#logo").offset().top;

    $('#logo').css('z-index',999).animate({ left: xrect + 'px', top: yrect + 'px' },2000);
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing such a thing without position absolute?

Comment: Yes, of course. But it was the easiest way to create an exemple : try by yourself : jsfiddle.net/YC68q/1